# Will not install - 12.10 desktop

Tags: installation

Just purchased 12.10 DVD but does not progress once the continue button is slected on the Preparing to install Ubuntu screen. Cursor indicates activity but no disk or CD activity. Am installing to replace Mandriva 2009.

Machine CPU is an old AMD Athlon XP 2000+ (1.6Ghz) with 1G RAM.

> 5G space available and network connected.

Tried all 3 copies provided and no difference.

Help - Mark S

Answer (score 1):

Mark, let's trouble shoot. Will Ubuntu 12.10 run as a live cd? Try that to narrow it down to possibly a hardware incompatibility. If not have you checked if all of your hardware (graphics cards, etc) are supported by Ubuntu? (most are..you can check [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/installation-guide/i386/hardware-supported.html) )

Also, it would be helpful if you could tell us make and model number of laptop, does it have an ATI graphics card and/or a uefi bios? If so, one of those may be the culprit.

Comment: Also, as jockster posted, try to see if it will boot up on a live cd (don't install). If you can get web access, other hardware works, you can narrow down to computer. I assume you have another operating system on there (windows 8 possibly)? If so it may be the UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

So you chose the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option? You don't say if you have the options selected or not? Does it make a difference or not?

There is not that much information to go on here, but some ideas:

Things I'd try (in this order):

- Use a Live CD to format wipe the HDD before running the installation again,
- Use the Live CD to test Ubuntu without installing, should indicate whether there is some fundamental incompatibility with some HW you have.
- Try downloading 12.10, burning a DVD and installing from that. Check the MD5SUM, to ensure it downloaded correctly, burn it at the slowest speed possible and with verification enabled.

HTH
J.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay in response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and apologies for the late response. Installed 11.04 and that worked fine but no support. Tried reinstalling 12.10 many times but always ends with  "The installer encountered an unrecoverable error". Tried the on-board VIA VGA, 64MB Nvidia Vanta TNT2, Nvidia Geforce FX5200 128MB. no progress. Have just downloaded 12.04LTS to try that.   Mark S

Comment: Neglected to mention - have limited internet so purchased the Desktop CDs for 12.10 - received 3 copies all same result.   Mark S

Comment: Installed 12.04 with no problem. Don't like the desktop. Needs better access to the available apps. Is there any way to get the latest version with the old desktop? Will revert to 11.04 if not.

Comment: @MarkSteve If the answer helped, please upvote it.